# Android "Bypassing user approval" for the second programmatically connection to a specific Wi-Fi network is not working

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

Following the Android documentation, I'm using this code to connect programmatically to a specific SSID:

```
private void connectToAP(String ssid, String password) {
   ...
   WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
     .setSsid(ssid)
     .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
     .build();

   NetworkRequest.Builder requestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
     .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
     .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
     .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);

   NetworkRequest request = requestBuilder.build();
   connManager.requestNetwork(request, myNetworkCallback);
   ...
   bindNetwork(); //this method will bind the network without internet
}
```

as described in the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-bootstrap#bypass-approval, if I don't forget the network, the second connection to that specific SSID have to bypass the user approval.

My problem is this:

1. Call "**connectToAP**"
2. User approval
3. Conneted
4. After a while the IoT device turns off the wifi for few seconds
5. The disconnection callback retries to call the "**connectToAP**" method (Point 1) but the user approval (Point 2) is not bypassed as expected

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Only put SSID on the wifi connectio specifier, with this work.

Comment: @FABiO as is in my example, but it is not working...also the second connection asks for the approval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here I attach a example for you val specifier, observe that the magic for this is at put in setBssid a value, with it thats ok and the system don`t show window aproval.

```
WifiNetworkSpecifier = if(isDevice8424){
                WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                    .setSsid(ssid)
                    .setBssid(MacAddress.fromString(bssid))//here ir the magic!
                    .build()
```

Comment: @Giovesoft With this, I am sure that in the second intent connection, the system do not question if do you like connection again. I wait that this can help you =)

Comment: thank you, with "setBssid" is working!

Comment: Great, greetings!!!